# MySQL Date Between

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**FIXED - this is what I have now** - Written in ASP

```
If Session("dateRange") = "Today" Then
        fromDate = Date()
        fromDate = Year(fromDate)&"-"&Month(fromDate)&"-"&Day(fromDate)
        whereClause = whereClause & "AND dateCreated = '"&fromDate&"' "
ElseIf Session("dateRange") = "Yesterday" Then
        fromDate = DateAdd("d",-1,Date())
        fromDate = Year(fromDate)&"-"&Month(fromDate)&"-"&Day(fromDate)
        whereClause = whereClause & "AND dateCreated = '"&fromDate&"' "
ElseIf Session("dateRange") = "1 Week" Then
        fromDate = DateAdd("d",-7,Date())
        fromDate = Year(fromDate)&"-"&Month(fromDate)&"-"&Day(fromDate)
        whereClause = whereClause & "AND dateCreated BETWEEN '"&fromDate&"' AND '"&toDate&"' "
ElseIf Session("dateRange") = "1 Month" Then
        fromDate = DateAdd("m",-1,Date())
        fromDate = Year(fromDate)&"-"&Month(fromDate)&"-"&Day(fromDate)
        whereClause = whereClause & "AND dateCreated BETWEEN '"&fromDate&"' AND '"&toDate&"' "
ElseIf Session("dateRange") = "3 Months" Then
        fromDate = DateAdd("m",-3,Date())
        fromDate = Year(fromDate)&"-"&Month(fromDate)&"-"&Day(fromDate)
        whereClause = whereClause & "AND dateCreated BETWEEN '"&fromDate&"' AND '"&toDate&"' "
ElseIf Session("dateRange") = "6 Months" Then
        fromDate = DateAdd("m",-6,Date())
        fromDate = Year(fromDate)&"-"&Month(fromDate)&"-"&Day(fromDate)
        whereClause = whereClause & "AND dateCreated BETWEEN '"&fromDate&"' AND '"&toDate&"' "
ElseIf Session("dateRange") = "1 Year" Then
        fromDate = DateAdd("yyyy",-1,Date())
        fromDate = Year(fromDate)&"-"&Month(fromDate)&"-"&Day(fromDate)
        whereClause = whereClause & "AND dateCreated BETWEEN '"&fromDate&"' AND '"&toDate&"' " 
End If
```

---

**Original Question:**

Simple question but for some reason I cannot seem to get this working.

I have a search box, next to that is a date-range select menu, so the user can search for photos within the last 1 month, 6 months or 12 months.

What I have does not error but it produces no results when it should do, this is it:

```
WHERE dateCreated BETWEEN "&DateAdd("m",-6,Date())&" AND "&Date()&"
```

The SQL output produces this:

```
dateCreated BETWEEN 18/03/2011 AND 18/09/2011 ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
```

The database 'dateCreated' field is set to (Date INDEX).

Can anybody see what is wrong?

Comment: Are you certain there's no error?

Comment: The dates in your SQL should be quoted with single quotes. And the in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The dates in your resulting SQL should be quoted with single quotes. Try surrounding the dynamic parts of your query with quotes. Something like this:

```
WHERE dateCreated BETWEEN '"&DateAdd("m",-6,Date())&"' AND '"&Date()&"'
```

which I assume would produce this SQL:

```
dateCreated BETWEEN '18/03/2011' AND '18/09/2011' ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
```

Also, see if you can find a way to format the dates in the more usual MySQL `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Like this:

```
dateCreated BETWEEN '2011-03-18' AND '2011-09-18' ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Asaph, this works now. My old date script was from a 'pants' access DB setup. So all I did was removed the "#"'s thinking that was all I needed to do. I hate date formats and databases!!

Answer (score 7):

If you are specifically looking backwards from "now", why not do

```
where DateCreated >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
where DateCreated >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH )
where DateCreated >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH )
```

No need for a "Range", just insert the month range back you want to allow...

Comment: Well actually, not all searches use the 'range', the user can insert two dates to find a more specific range... but... if the user uses the basic range, I could build the SQL just for that and if they enter two dates, I could build the SQL just for that too because I'm sure your suggestion is quicker for looking backwards

Answer (score 2):

`%d-%m-%Y` is not a proper date format and date values in MySQL should be always quoted alike strings and ISO 8601 (`'%Y-%m-%d'`) format. `18/03/2011` will be interpreted as just `18` divided by `03` and `2011` which gives about `0.002…`.

That is to say, your SQL should be like the following form instead:

```
dateCreated BETWEEN '2011-03-18' AND '2011-09-18' ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what technology you're using for `DateAdd()`, but your final date format is wrong in addition to the fact that your date values are not enclosed by single quotes.

MySQL compares dates as `2011-03-18` not `18/03/2011`.

A note that you can do this in MySQL with its [Date Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Although it *may* keep the query from being cached.

Answer (score 0):

If those strings are unquoted, I believe you are actually just doing division and then comparing the dates between a very small timeframe.