# count mysql table field on the basis of time intervals

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have subscription table which includes all subscription pf advertisement related to screen. I want to restrict user to add only 20 ads per screen at a time. I am done with ads count per screen. but, the problem is, I want to consider date range (start date and end date of each subscription) . That means the ads shouldn't be more than 20 within particular date range.

I have built sample schema in sqlfiddle.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/070cf/1

Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit imprecise. To what range are you trying to limit the count? In the mean time, explore the `GROUP BY` and, possibly, `HAVING` clauses.

Comment: Yes. There is a start date and end date for each subscription. Within this range advertises should be less than 20.

Comment: So are you trying to create a check if there are already the max number of entries in the DB for the period/ user before entering any entry in the DB?

Comment: Then what's the issue? Simply get the number of advertisements for the user in the date range from the DB and in case the value is lesser than the max value, insert into DB else show relevant message.

Comment: I have no idea on checking date range. Can you check sqlfiddle link, which I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @AkshatSinghal, it'S not that simple. If you search for a 30 day period, and you have 10 subscriptions that end in the first day and 10 that start in the last day, your count is 20, but you can actually add 10 subscriptions in that period.

Comment: @user3067928 this should be done with a loop in the application layer, not in the database layer. You need to loop through each date in the period and check if the negative condition (>20) is met.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the condition for every day in the interval. this is something that I strongly advise doing i nthe application layer, as mysql is really not built for this looping.

But for the sake of argument, here'S how to tackle it in sql:
1. Expand the searched interval to all of the days
2. Check condition for each day

Step 1: Expanding an interval

```
select *, start_date+interval nr.number day as search_date -- search date is the exploded interval
from
(select date('2013-01-13') as start_date, date('2013-02-20') as end_date) search -- the dates we search for
inner join -- joining a numbers table to expand the interval
(select a.nr+b.nr*10 as number from
    (select 1 as nr
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 5
    union all select 6
    union all select 7
    union all select 8
    union all select 9
    union all select 0
    )a
    join
    (select 1 as nr
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 5
    union all select 6
    union all select 7
    union all select 8
    union all select 9
    union all select 0
    )b
    order by 1 asc
) nr
on nr.number<=datediff(end_date, start_date)
```

Now you have the columns start_date, end_date, search_date, where search date contains all dates between start and end. Let's call this query 'date_interval'

Assume you have a table with other date_start and date_end, as per your subscription table. To calculate if your condition of no more than 20 campaigns per day is met, andto find the offending days, we join like so:

```
select search_date, count(*) as subscriptions_active from
date_interval as di
inner join 
subscriptions as s 
on di.search_date between s.date_start and s.date_end
group by search_date
having subscriptions_active <20
```

resulting in a table of dates with 20 or more campaigns from our searched interval.

Another approach would be checking the running total, whcih would work with datetime. 
Suppose table subscriptions with start_date and end_date, query example is below. Now it is easy to check if there exists a datetime between the searched start and end date in this table that does not meet the condition.

```
select c.date, c.change_,

(select sum(change_) from   (select start_date as date, change_ from 
        (select start_date , 1 as change_ from 
                (select date('2013-01-13') as start_date, date('2013-02-20') as end_date
                union all
                select date('2013-01-14') as start_date, date('2013-04-25') as end_date
                union all
                select date('2013-03-15') as start_date, date('2013-05-25') as end_date)a
        union
        select end_date, -1 as change_ from 
                (select date('2013-01-13') as start_date, date('2013-02-20') as end_date
                union all
                select date('2013-01-14') as start_date, date('2013-04-25') as end_date
                union all
                select date('2013-03-15') as start_date, date('2013-05-12') as end_date)a
        order by 1 asc)b
    )d where d.date<=c.date) as running_total










 from

    (select start_date as date, change_ from 
        (select start_date , 1 as change_ from 
                (select date('2013-01-13') as start_date, date('2013-02-20') as end_date
                union all
                select date('2013-01-14') as start_date, date('2013-04-25') as end_date
                union all
                select date('2013-03-15') as start_date, date('2013-05-25') as end_date)a
        union
        select end_date, -1 as change_ from 
                (select date('2013-01-13') as start_date, date('2013-02-20') as end_date
                union all
                select date('2013-01-14') as start_date, date('2013-04-25') as end_date
                union all
                select date('2013-03-15') as start_date, date('2013-05-12') as end_date)a
        order by 1 asc)b
    )c
```

Answer (score 0):

If the start and enddate are inputs to your select statement:

```
SELECT count(screen_id) as ad_count
FROM subscription  
WHERE  
  screen_id=1 AND 
  DATE_START >= STR_TO_DATE('19,01,2014','%d,%m,%Y') and  
  DATE_END <= STR_TO_DATE('23,01,2014','%d,%m,%Y');
```

Comment: No. It's dynamic. It's already in the database table. check sqlfiddle link.

Comment: what are your inputs to this query and what is the expected outcome? do you want to check if any agent is above this limit?

Comment: yes. I need to check, total subscription count not more than 20 within start and end date range, before any agent adds new subscription.

Comment: then get the start and enddates, as well as the agentid from the new subscription he/she wants to make and run
SELECT count(screen_id) as ad_count FROM subscription WHERE screen_id=1 AND
screen_id=1 and agent_id=1 and
 DATE_START >=STR_TO_DATE('19,01,2014','%d,%m,%Y')
and
DATE_END<= STR_TO_DATE('23,01,2014','%d,%m,%Y');

Comment: @RomanPickl it's not that simple. If you search for a 30 day period, and you have 10 subscriptions that end in the first day and 10 that start in the last day, your count is 20, but you can actually add 10 subscriptions in that period. –

Comment: @AdrianBR Really depends on the use case here (see above "AkshatSinghal: Yes. That's what I need."). i assume the agent 1 requests a subscription for screen 1 for a specific timeframe. so you can now check if this is a valid time window. which would also depend on the resolution (are we talking about days/hours/ or any given time?)

searching for the next available timewindow is, as you said, a different problem

Comment: there is a "between" keyword that is much easier to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464271/mysql-date-between

Comment: there are two dates involved though

Comment: @RomanPickl User fails to see the shortcomings of the above method, and what he said he needs is clearly not meeting his specs. a simple count of campaigns in the time frame is insufficient, he rather needs the greatest count of campaigns on any single date in the period. Myself I had a similar membership case a couple of years back, and this would be done much much easier in the application layer. THere is a way you can do this in mysql, but it's very ugly on maintainability and speed(join on interval to generate dates, join on dates to calculate count for each date, take max).

Comment: @AdrianBR what if the interval is <1 day?

Comment: @RomanPickl His dump clearly shows date and not datetime. But you are correct, this is by far not the best implementation. The best implementation is in the application layer.

Comment: Nevertleless, if the fields were to have been datetime and the requirement was sql, then the problem is solved by splitting the interval into sub-intervals at every encountered datetime from the existing subscriptions, and doing a count of subscriptions for those sub intervals. Another approach is to have a calculated running count table(select date, (select sum(count) from table a where a.date <=b.date)  as running_count from table b), again, for each exiting datetime, each end substracting 1, each start adding 1.

Comment: @RomanPickl added example for the datetime. This is not something you want in a database though.