# how to calculate the business days and holidays using mysql

Tags: mysql

i am trying to calculate the business days of specific months 
and i have week work days
[image]

in this images Friday and Saturday is not business days

and also i have holiday table

[image]

the question is how to calculate the work days dynamically between start_date and end_date of specific monthes

your help will be approciated

Comment: Check out 'BETWEEN' as your where clause.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464271/mysql-date-between

Comment: USE SUM() function on BETWEEN condition

Comment: 1. See normalization. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: can you guys help me out to right a query for this?