# How to get 0-30 days record, 30-60 and 60 -90 and above 90 in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my project, i want to take record of 0-30 days, 30-60days, 60-90 days and 90 above record. Currently i fetch 0-30 days records, how to get rest of things from mysql database. i have attached my code below. I am doing my project in codeigniter.

```
public function outstandingMonth(){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM zemco_tbl_invoice a left join zemco_tbl_payment b on (a.invoice_no=b.payment_invoice_id) WHERE invoice_status = 2 AND invoice_modified_time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()");
}
```

Can any one help me to solve this, thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please share your tables' structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: this might be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464271/mysql-date-between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess without knowing the exactly structure of your database, but would that not do the trick?

```
invoice_modified_time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()

invoice_modified_time BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)

invoice_modified_time BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass `days` range intervals as input parameter to the function, you can use them in the query to fetch records.

Modified query is shown as Example below:

```
SELECT * FROM zemco_tbl_invoice a 
  left join zemco_tbl_payment b on (a.invoice_no=b.payment_invoice_id) 
 WHERE invoice_status = 2 
   AND invoice_modified_time BETWEEN ( NOW() - INTERVAL $toDays DAY )
                                 AND ( NOW() - INTERVAL $fromDays DAY )
```

If you want to fetch records between 30 and 60 days, then `fromDays` is `30` and `toDays` is 60. Then above query would result as below:

```
SELECT * FROM zemco_tbl_invoice a 
  LEFT JOIN zemco_tbl_payment b ON a.invoice_no = b.payment_invoice_id 
 WHERE invoice_status = 2 
   AND invoice_modified_time BETWEEN ( NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY )
                                 AND ( NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY )
```

You can make use of the input parameters for the method as desired and use in the query as desired.